# Rails - how to store large numbers like 100000076685963

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I need to store large numbers like :100000076685963

Which are to big for a db field type of integer. In my db migration I use:

```
  t.integer :fb_uid
```

what field type should I use for large numbers like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use a fixed-point datatype such as decimal with a large precision. Based on the number you've given, a precision of 15 will work but you should figure out exactly what range you are expecting.

```
t.decimal :fb_fluid, :precision => 15
```

Comment: It's for storing facebook uID so it could hit 1 billion

Answer (score 3):

Try float

```
t.float :fb_uid
```

And seems like this is something to do with Facebook (probably facebooker) and assuming these numbers will not use as arithmetic operations, you could probably use just string

```
t.string :fb_uid
```

Comment: Float fields have a limited precision and are "lossy"; the number you get out may not be the number you put in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `limit` field in for the column to get Postgresql's `bigint` precision:

```
t.integer :fb_uid, limit: 8
```